# How can I get a Proof of a Concord Well Kept?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I know how to obtain the normal version, but I have no clue how to get a Proof of a Concord Well Kept to drop for me in any way. How do I get one? I know that killing an invading dark spirit when summoned to another world as a Blue Sentinel or a Blade of the Darkmoon will get me one, but how do I obtain a Well Kept Proof from a standard summoning?

Comment: There isn't a way to get it from a standard summoning.

Comment: @Vemonus what do you mean?

Comment: read my answer. You have to be summoned into someone's world as a Blade of the Darkmoon and kill an invading member of Rosaria's Fingers. That's the only way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to get a Proof of a Concord Well Kept, according to [the wiki page](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Proof+of+a+Concord+Well+Kept) is to be summoned as a Blade of the Darkmoon and then kill an invading dark spirit that is a member of Rosaria's Fingers. **This item is not dropped any other way**. In fact, the wiki dispels a misconception that people have about where to get this item:

> It is a common misconception that these drop from Aldrich Faithfuls after killing them. However, this is not the case, even if the player lands the killing blow on them.

Comment: Having done /so many invasions/ this seems inaccurate, otherwise I'd have way, way more Well Kept Concords. In my experience I've only seen them drop under one single circumstance: I was summoned as a Sentinel/Blade to a host who had used Dried Fingers and I killed a Mad Phantom, a Mound Maker. All of those things are required. I'm a blue, the host has used dried fingers, I kill an invading purple (not an aldrich). If it was as easy as merely killing a red, how would we even get regular concords, which we get from killing reds? No rewards for killing aldrich...

Comment: It's too bad it's so hard to test, since we can't exactly "force" two random summons at once to a single testing host. These can't be "soapstone" summons after all...